# jQuery Best way to do this, looping functions

Tags: jquery

This is more a question of how would you go about doing this than a specific problem.

Say i have 5 divs called div1, div2, div3, div4, div5. Whats the quickest/best way to make a looping function such as the one below that will loop a certain div (not all the divs on the page) if it is clicked.

Heres the best way i can think of explaining it.

Div1 is clicked. A function is called that checks div1 is listed as a div that should loop. Then starts the looping function. Div6 is clicked, but is not listed as a div that can loop and the function is not run.

```
function div1loop() {
        $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()    {
            $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.1, div1loop);  
        });
}
```

Is there any way you could suggest that could the "#div1" part a variable so that i would not have to write 5 different functions for the 5 separate divs?

For a bit of background info -
Im going to end up having 50+ divs to do this for, and as you can imagine, it would save me a lot of time if i could make  a function that could do this instead of 50.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it to be in a constant state of flux? Because as you have it there, whatever it is you are fading in or out will never stop fading in and out, unless you specifically make it stop.

Comment: Which is why he should unflag the div in some way after the work has been done-- see my answer below which uses a CSS class to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
function divloop(selector) {
   $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()    {
       $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.1, function() { divloop(selector); });  
   });
}
```

Then :

```
divloop("#div1");
```

Edit :
You've 2 options:

1. Store selectors allowed in an array :

   ```
   var allowedDivs = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3" ];
   ```

   and in divloop :

   ```
   function divloop(selector) {
       if(!$.inArray(selector, allowedDivs ) {
           return false;
       }
       $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()    {
          $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.1, function() { divloop(selector); });  
       });
   }
   ```
2. Or add a class to your div that you can check in your function

   ```
   <div id="div1" class="canLoop"></div>
   ```

   Then in your function :

   ```
   function divloop(selector) {
       if(!$(selector).hasClass("canLoop")) {
           return false;
       }
       $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()    {
          $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 0.1, function() { divloop(selector); });  
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Would you be able to add a bit more information? How would i make sure only certain divs would start this function? Thank rohk

Comment: Store divs that can start this function in an array, or add a class to them, then check that selector passed to divloop is allowed...

Comment: this is exactly why classes were invented-- to refer to a unique group of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to the divs you are referring to-- something like .flagged and add/remove it after you have processed the work for that div by using $('.flagged').toggleClass().

```
$('.flagged').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flagged');
})
```

If you are needing to process each div seperately (instead all at the same time) then do

```
$('.flagged').each(function(i, item){

    $(item).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flagged');
    })

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) should help you out.  For instance, to reference any div which has an id of the form "div#", you could use

```
$('[id^=div]')
```

which translates to "any id that begins with div" or more generally

```
$('[id*=div]')
```

which translates to "any id that contains div".

That should get you pointed in the right direction.